# value of rD (Modelica)

Tags: modelica

I'm new to modelica.
What is the evaluated value of **rD** in the following modelica Code ?

```
model A
    Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = 4;

    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        Real rC = rA;
    end B;

    B myB;
    

    Real rD = myB.rC;

    // What is the result of the evaluation of rD ?
    // Case A : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 4 = 5 
    // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner/outer references to propagate the value of `rA` from top-level model `A` to component model `B`.

Based on this, for case A the code looks like:

```
model A
  inner Real rA=1 + rB;
  Real rB=4;

  model B
    outer Real rA;
    Real rB=10;
    Real rC=rA;
  end B;

  B myB;


  Real rD=myB.rC;

  // What is the result of the evaluation of rD ?
  // Case A : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 4 = 5 
  // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

For case B:

```
model A
    inner Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = myB.rB;

    model B
        outer Real rA;
        Real rB = 10;
        Real rC = rA;
    end B;

    B myB;
    Real rD = myB.rC;

    // What is the result of the evaluation of rD ?
    // Case A : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 4 = 5 
    // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

Hope this works!